# VS2010 rdlc report unable to embed dataset using Oracle

Tags: c#

I am using VS2010 and oracle as a database. I am trying to create a rdlc dynamic report using dataset. But I cant embed the dataset in rdlc report as I can do in VS2008. If anybody knows then please let me know with detailed code.